# Load raw HTML files in Kohana

Tags: html, view, kohana

I'm needing to load a series of auto-generated HTML files (source code docs) that are already self-contained in a directory. How can I get Kohana to load these files? (If I try to use my existing controller/view setup Kohana doesn't recognize the HTML files - index.php for example, in the directory)

Comment: Correction: index.php should be index.html. I just need the raw HTML files to render without the intervention of Kohana, if possible...

Comment: What version of kohana are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the files in the same folder as your other static assets (stylesheets, javascripts, images).

Comment: Gerry - you da man! Works like a charm! (version of Kohana is v2.2, as defined in kohana/system/core/bootstrap.php)

Answer (score 0):

To render a html page as a part of a route.

ie. Route : GET /resource/action
    Static HTML : /public/static.html

```
        $this->auto_render = false;
        // render cached file
        echo file_get_contents('public/static.html');
```